# class in class, bug in ie6

Tags: html, css, class, internet-explorer-6

I'm writting HTML/css code and have a specific bug in IE6.

I want to create changeable div's, using classes:

For example (this is just example, not real-project code)

```
.top {width: 50px;}
.top.selected {background: #f00;}
.mid {width: 114px;}
.mid.selected {background: #0f0;}
.bot {width: 100px;}
.bot.selected {background: #0ff; color: #f00;}
...etc...
```

so, html will be like a:

```
<div class='top selected'>1</div>
<div class='mid'>2</div>
<div class='bot selected'>3</div>
```

It will be great for programmer, but it doesn't work in IE6 :(

Only `.topselected {background: #f00;} // <div class='top topselected'>`
, but it's realy dirty code... Maybe some there are some hacks?

Comment: Support for IE6... seriously?

Comment: Crozin, yes. I think, if html-coder can't write crossbrowser-code, he is a newbie... It's not too hard to add some **!important** tags.

Comment: Even Microsoft abandoned IE6. Time to move on. Oh, and cross-browser coding doesn't apply to IE6. It applies to browsers that follow standards.

Comment: congratulations, you open new world of IE for yourself:) probably conditional classes for html tag is what you need, or at least confitional stylesheets

Comment: You are going to waste the double or triple time to do the workaround, your code and design will turn to ugly and all that hard work will be just because of less than 1% of people in the world, probably no one.

Comment: @j08691 Add IE7 to that. Stats for IE7 show that fewer people use IE7 now than used IE6 at the beginning of this year. They're both buried.

Comment: IE6 doesn't support compound classes like that in CSS selectors.  If you really need it that badly, the only way you'll get it is in the form of a JavaScript polyfill (if one exists).  IE6 is a long dead relic, let it go.

Comment: @jrrtGimli: So why don't you write plain assembly code for all processors when you create a program? You are a newbie if you can't do that. Writing code for IE6 actually is like writing assembly for executables nowdays. Except when you are writing drivers, which in "browser" situation can be converted in "except when you are writing an app for a very old company". Clean code is much more important than IE6 support, if you don't understand that, **you** are a newbie.

Comment: I solved problem, using russian community: http://chicowebdesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/multiple-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the way to go here would be to create more semantic class names and then split them out like so:

```
.highlighted { background: #0f0; }
.wide { width: 114px; }
/* etc... */
```

and then the html you have will work well and IMO, be more maintainable.

Comment: IE6 doesn't support mutiple classes!

Comment: @falsarella IE6 does support `class="foo bar"` but not CSS `.foo.bar`, therefore this is valid.

Comment: In your example, will it recognize the `foo` class? I thought that it would just recognize the `bar` class even if used `.foo{} .bar{}` it would ignore the `foo` css declaration...

Comment: @fasarella: It does recognize all of them. Here's a test you can run with BrowserStack or Sauce Labs: http://jsfiddle.net/uJsJv/ - I just verified it.